# can you write a halting decider that is only wrong about itself by avoiding diagonalization?

Tags: turing-machines, halting-problem

in [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0504351.pdf) they claim: "there is an algorithm deciding almost all instances of [halting problem]"

so I'm wonder whether there is a computable function $h':\mathbb{N}\to\{0,1\}$ such that the following turing machine is a halting decider (for TMs running on blank input) except for itself

$$
\begin{align*}
M(m) &=
   \begin{cases}
      \text{loop in state $q_{accept}$} & \text{if $h'(m)=1$} \\
      \text{halt in state $q_{accept}$} & \text{if $h'(m)=0$} \\
   \end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$

for me as a programmer $h'$ is very interesting function because it connect arithmetic to turing machines

[image]

Comment: don't you mean h' is a halting decider? since it returns 0 or 1 depending on whether a program halts?

Comment: The paper says that if you create programs at random, you're quite likely to get one that can be proven to halt or not halt. But it's also using a weird kind of Turing machines where it's possible to "halt without halting". I'm not sure it generalizes to the usual sort of Turing machines.

Comment: @user253751 if you trust the consistency of Peano Arithmetic then there is an algorithm that solve almost all instances of halting problem and all instances that it can't recognize are looping instances so if you print 0 first and try to search for a proof of halting status of the input program if you find a proof then you have 00 or 01 as output but if you don't find a proof then you have 0 as output

Comment: then you haven't solved the halting problem. The halting problem has two answers but your program has 3 answers.

Comment: The paper has two kinds of halting. One of them isn't called "halting". They call them "halting" and "falling off the tape". But it's really the same as two kinds of halting.

Comment: How does the halting decider detect whether it is simulating itself? You can add some no-op states to any Turing machine and it will always compute the same answers. Is it then "itself"? Or I can make one that scans the first 100,000,000,000 integers for Collatz conjecture counterexamples, and goes back to the halting decider if it doesn't find one. Will that still be considered as diagonalization?

Comment: @user253751 I commented before (but it's gone now I don't know why) that my question is not quite right because I confused halting on blank input and halting on itself. but anyway, I think it always come back to diagonalization, in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%27s_thesis_(constructive_mathematics)) it says "adding either the law of the excluded middle or Church's thesis does not make Heyting arithmetic inconsistent, but adding both does", and that is my problem with the halting problem

Comment: that's just another way of saying not all functions are computable. Church's thesis applies to a kind of limited mathematics where uncomputable functions don't exist because all uncomputable functions are too complicated for that kind of mathematics. If you make the mathematics less limited, you may discover there are functions that aren't computable and that obviously contradicts Church's thesis.

Comment: @user253751 now that I thought a little bit more I'm interested in this language: 
$$
\begin{align*}
contradictory=\{\langle M,w\rangle|\text{$M$ diverges on $w$ or $M$ is $contradictory$}\}
\end{align*}
$$
can you solve it?

Comment: you are interested in sets that contain themselves (plus some other stuff)? seems like a set theory question. Due to Russell's Paradox such sets are generally no longer considered to exist.

Comment: @user253751 my main interest is creating new technologies (if I can create a wormhole then I would be happy :D) but unfortunately I fall into the black hole of philosophy that I don't have any interest. right now I'm thinking about computability, is it possible that everything is turing computable and there is a way to overcome diagonalization?

Comment: I want 1+1 to be 3, is it possible that 1+1=3 and there is a way to overcome arithmetic? I want perpetual motion, is it possible that energy is not conserved and there is a way to overcome Noether's theorem?

Comment: @user253751 imagine that you discovered a new law and using that law you created 2 object and when you put one near the other a third one appears out of nowhere so 1+1=3, if the universe is non-physical then you must get used to seeing glitches all over the place even if it is physical I guess there are so many undiscovered laws

Comment: That law was discovered - the objects were called mommy and daddy and baby. However 1+1 is still 2. That is like saying you disproved the halting problem by proving that a program doesn't halt.

Comment: @user253751 it seems like you are not a sci-fi fan? and you know physics at least more than me? do you know anything about non-computable theory of quantum gravity?

Comment: nobody knowing what the theory is, has nothing to do with computability

Comment: @user253751 then how do we know that it is non-computable?

Comment: we don't......?

Comment: @user253751 can you answer my new question [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/156693/is-there-an-unsound-solution-to-the-halting-problem-that-makes-the-following-fun)?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. If you had a procedure $M$ that would correctly solve the Halting problem for all but finitely many instances $p_0,p_1,\ldots,p_k$, then there would exist a computable solution to the Halting problem as follows:

Input $p$

if $p = p_0$, return $b_0$

elseif $p = p_1$, return $b_1$

...

elseif $p = p_k$, return $b_k$

else return M(p)

If the $b_i$ are correctly chosen, this is solving the Halting problem. (We don't necessarily have a way to figure out the correct choice, but it clearly exists.)

So if we take the usual reading of "almost all" to mean "all but finitely many exceptions", we cannot solve the Halting problem for almost all instances. But that is not what the paper you've linked is claiming. They say that for one natural encoding, we can solve the Halting problem for a set of instances $I$ such that $\frac{|I \cap \{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}|}{n}$ tends to $1$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: I linked to the paper as a motivation for my question but my question does not depend on the paper, I'm asking is there a TM that solves the halting problem for all instances except itself by adding a loop transition to the accepting state to avoid diagonalization meaning $M(M)$ is wrong and you can't use $M$ as a subroutine in another turing machine because it has a loop transition in it's accepting state

Comment: @raoof And I'm telling you that you can't get "solves all but finitely many instances", no matter what you do.

Comment: @raoof: You are asking whether one can build a Halting Decider that can Decide the Halting Problem for all except *one* instance and this answer explains why it is impossible to build a Halting Decider that can Decide the Halting Problem for all except *a finite number* of instances. Since one is a finite number, this more general answer also answers your question.

Comment: @JörgWMittag the problem with this answer is that you can't call $M(p)$ because it loops on infinitely many inputs, I'm arguing that if we use the counter example to $h'$ as the halting decider then there is no other counter example, the only counter example is $M$ itself

Comment: The paper also seems to use a trick by redefining what halting is. IMO it is more natural to either consider a tape that is infinite in both directions. The paper's argument is: random programs move randomly on the tape; most random walks eventually go off the left edge of the tape; therefore most random programs do stop running eventually.